# Eve SQLAlchemy query catenation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eve

I can do `http://127.0.0.1:5000/people?where={"lastname":"like(\"Smi%\")"}` to get `people.lastname LIKE "Smi%"`

How do I  concat two conditions, like where city=XX and pop<1000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple you just do:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/people?where={"city":"XX", "pop":"<1000"}`